# How old must you be to file a patent

Tags: legal

My kid (14 years old) is pretty innovative and has a great idea that he wants to write a patent for -- himself.

I know enough about patents to know that he probably can't do a good enough job himself to file a patent that can offer much protection, however, I want him to do it just for the learning experience of it. It doesn't cost much to file.

My question though is: is there a lower age limit for filing? Can someone under the age of majority file a patent? (Jurisdiction is the USA.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no age requirements for patents, because technically only the TRUE INVENTOR can apply for a patent.  If you filed for a patent under your name and later it was discovered your son was the inventor, there would be legal consequences.

Your son can very likely write a pretty good application with a little help. You need this book: [Patent It Yourself](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1413317197)

It is absolutely fantastic!  Good luck to you son!